# pip does not install all of the packages if I ask it to do it just once

Tags: python, pip

I have a fresh installation of `python3` and `python3-pip` on Ubuntu.

I invoked the command:

```sh
pip3 install ansible packaging msrestazure docker-py ansible[azure] openshift
```

Then I invoked `pip3 list`. Here's the result:

```
root@7e8175337b62:/# pip3 list
Package             Version
------------------- ---------
adal                1.2.4
ansible             2.9.11
cachetools          4.1.1
certifi             2020.6.20
cffi                1.14.1
chardet             3.0.4
cryptography        3.0
docker-py           1.10.6
docker-pycreds      0.4.0
google-auth         1.20.0
idna                2.10
isodate             0.6.0
Jinja2              2.11.2
kubernetes          11.0.0
MarkupSafe          1.1.1
msrest              0.6.18
msrestazure         0.6.4
oauthlib            3.1.0
openshift           0.11.2
packaging           20.4
pip                 20.0.2
pyasn1              0.4.8
pyasn1-modules      0.2.8
pycparser           2.20
PyJWT               1.7.1
pyparsing           2.4.7
python-dateutil     2.8.1
python-string-utils 1.0.0
PyYAML              5.3.1
requests            2.24.0
requests-oauthlib   1.3.0
rsa                 4.6
ruamel.yaml         0.16.10
ruamel.yaml.clib    0.2.0
setuptools          45.2.0
six                 1.15.0
urllib3             1.25.10
websocket-client    0.57.0
wheel               0.34.2
```

I saw that not all of the azure packages got installed. So, I run `pip3 install ansible[azure]` this time, although I already asked pip to install that package. After installation finishes, this is the result of `pip3 list`:

```
root@7e8175337b62:/# pip3 list
Package                        Version
------------------------------ ---------
adal                           1.2.4
ansible                        2.9.11
applicationinsights            0.11.9
argcomplete                    1.12.0
azure-cli-core                 2.0.35
azure-cli-nspkg                3.0.2
azure-common                   1.1.11
azure-graphrbac                0.40.0
azure-keyvault                 1.0.0a1
azure-mgmt-authorization       0.51.1
azure-mgmt-automation          0.1.1
azure-mgmt-batch               5.0.1
azure-mgmt-cdn                 3.0.0
azure-mgmt-compute             4.4.0
azure-mgmt-containerinstance   1.4.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry   2.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerservice    4.4.0
azure-mgmt-cosmosdb            0.5.2
azure-mgmt-devtestlabs         3.0.0
azure-mgmt-dns                 2.1.0
azure-mgmt-hdinsight           0.1.0
azure-mgmt-iothub              0.7.0
azure-mgmt-keyvault            1.1.0
azure-mgmt-loganalytics        0.2.0
azure-mgmt-marketplaceordering 0.1.0
azure-mgmt-monitor             0.5.2
azure-mgmt-network             2.3.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg               2.0.0
azure-mgmt-rdbms               1.4.1
azure-mgmt-redis               5.0.0
azure-mgmt-resource            2.1.0
azure-mgmt-servicebus          0.5.3
azure-mgmt-sql                 0.10.0
azure-mgmt-storage             3.1.0
azure-mgmt-trafficmanager      0.50.0
azure-mgmt-web                 0.41.0
azure-nspkg                    2.0.0
azure-storage                  0.35.1
bcrypt                         3.1.7
cachetools                     4.1.1
certifi                        2020.6.20
cffi                           1.14.1
chardet                        3.0.4
colorama                       0.4.3
cryptography                   3.0
docker-py                      1.10.6
docker-pycreds                 0.4.0
google-auth                    1.20.0
humanfriendly                  8.2
idna                           2.10
isodate                        0.6.0
Jinja2                         2.11.2
jmespath                       0.10.0
knack                          0.3.3
kubernetes                     11.0.0
MarkupSafe                     1.1.1
msrest                         0.6.1
msrestazure                    0.5.0
oauthlib                       3.1.0
openshift                      0.11.2
packaging                      20.4
paramiko                       2.7.1
pip                            20.0.2
pyasn1                         0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                 0.2.8
pycparser                      2.20
Pygments                       2.6.1
PyJWT                          1.7.1
PyNaCl                         1.4.0
pyOpenSSL                      19.1.0
pyparsing                      2.4.7
python-dateutil                2.8.1
python-string-utils            1.0.0
PyYAML                         5.3.1
requests                       2.24.0
requests-oauthlib              1.3.0
rsa                            4.6
ruamel.yaml                    0.16.10
ruamel.yaml.clib               0.2.0
setuptools                     45.2.0
six                            1.15.0
tabulate                       0.8.2
urllib3                        1.25.10
websocket-client               0.57.0
wheel                          0.30.0
xmltodict                      0.12.0
```

As you can see, the second time I requested the installation of `ansible[azure]` it actually installed all the packages. Why didn't it work the first time I asked?

Comment: But you executed `pip3 install ansible`, then you executed `pip3 install ansible[azure]`. Could this be the reason?

Comment: @AhmetTavli The first time I wanted to install both `ansible` and `ansible[azure]` (and other things). I don't understand why it did not install all of the packages of `ansible[azure]`

Comment: Are they two separate packages?

Comment: @AhmetTavli My pip knowledge is rather limited. All I know is that I need both `ansible` and `ansible[azure]` to be installed.

Comment: If possible could you please execute the command `pip3 install packaging msrestazure docker-py ansible[azure] openshift`. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: As you can see my first command successfully installed `ansible` - it can be seen in the `pip3 list` output. However, none of the `azure-mgmt-*` packages got installed. When I explicitly asked for just `ansible[azure]` all of the `azure-mgmt-*` got installed.

Comment: @AhmetTavli I'm not sure if you understand my problem. I'd like to install all of the packages that I need in one command. That's why I used `pip3 install ansible packaging msrestazure docker-py ansible[azure] openshift`. However, for some reason, it doesn't install `azure-mgmt-*` packages, which, I guess, come with `ansible[azure]`. Why is that?

Comment: I saw you typed `ansible` and `ansible[azure]`. I thought the first `ansible` is unnecssary, so I removed,  If you try it, I guess it solves it

Comment: @AhmetTavli I just tried your proposal - it worked! Could you explain why it helped? My understanding is that `ansible[azure]` already contains `ansible`, so pip sees that and ignores `ansible[azure]` entirely? Such behavior would be very weird I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- `pip3 install packaging ansible msrestazure docker-py ansible[azure] openshift`

2- `pip3 install packaging msrestazure docker-py ansible[azure] openshift`

Why the first one install all the `azure` packages? but the second is just only installing `ansible`?

The reason is, when `ansible[azure]` is executed, `pip` checks whether the `ansible` package is installed or not. The `ansible` package is installed in the first place (`pip3 install ansible`). Therefore the time we execute `pip3 install ansible[azure]`, `pip` thought all the necessary packages were installed. Therefore skips the remaining and the crucial `azure` packages.

Since this is a long explanation I couldn't fit into the comment section. Therefore, I wrote as an answer.

Comment: The commands should be written the other way round - the first one fails, the second one succeeds.

Comment: I believe it is a proper way to write answers as ANSWERS, not as comments, it is easier to find them :) Thanks

Comment: I think that pip's logic is pretty bad here. I consider it as a major issue. You expect it to install some packages, but it actually does not do that for some reason.

Comment: @Loreno If you want you can post the issue to their [github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues) page. Maybe they changed the logic the way you want

Comment: Good idea. I'll do that